# same bash test command but getting two results, reproducible

Tags: bash

This is an hilarious, reproducible error:

```
$ echo $retval
0
$ test $retval -eq 0 && echo si
si
$ test $retval -eq 0 && echo si
-bash: test 0: command not found
```

any hint?

Comment: I don’t think that’s a normal space after “test” in the last command. Maybe a non-breaking space?

Comment: Note how the error message states it was looking for the command „test 0“ - not „test“ nor „test 0 -eq 0“. You have merged the word test and its first argument with an invisible character that is not a regular space.

Comment: What version of bash in witch environment? What, where is this `$retval` variable set?

Comment: Can't reproduce it on my side. I can repeat the last command as often as I want and I always get `si` as output. If @MisterMiyagi 's theory is correct, and I find it believable, it's not reflected in how you put the code in the question. If the third command is actually identical to the second and this is not a trick, you'll need to tell us your OS and version of bash if you want anyone to be able to find a solution, as Léa Gris asked.